# How can I return user to original switch menu from do-while loop?

Tags: c++

how can I get user to go back to original switch menu once the user selects N at the end. When user selects N, would I use another loop to get them back to original menu? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
cout << "Total Chips: " << chips << endl;
cout << "1) xxxxx" << endl;
cout << "2) xxx" << endl;
cout << "Please enter an option" << endl;
int option;
cin >> option;


switch(option)
{
    case 1: 
    {
        char again;
        
        do
        {
            /* code
            */
            
        cout << "Would you like to play again? Y/N" << endl;
        cin >> again;
        }while(towlower(again) == 'y'); // I'm not sure whether to use another do-while loop.
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Hint: `while (running)`.

Comment: Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted. Repeated low-quality questions may result in a temporary ban from asking new questions.

Comment: Use functions. When you put complicated code inside a `switch`, especially `switch`s inside `switch`s, you're asking for trouble. But if you have `switch` where the `case`s call functions that contain the next `switch`, loop, or what-have-you, you can easily `return` from the function to move back a step. Plus you wind up with small, easily individually testable building blocks rather than a huge nested monolith with dozens of different paths that must all be validated.

Comment: Follow the ancient Unix maxim: Do one thing and do it well. The less a function does, the better it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When user selects N, would I use another loop to get them back to original menu?

Yes, one that is put around the original menu, eg:

```
bool keepRunning = true;

do {
    cout << "Total Chips: " << chips << endl;
    cout << "1) xxxxx" << endl;
    cout << "2) xxx" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter an option" << endl;

    int option;
    cin >> option;

    switch (option)
    {
        case 1: 
        {
            char again;
        
            do
            {
                /* code
                */
            
                cout << "Would you like to play again? Y/N" << endl;
                cin >> again;
            }
            while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y');

            break;
        }

        ...
    }
}
while (keepRunning);
```